# config.ru file for Rails 2.3.18 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rack, unicorn

Does anyone know what the contents of `config.ru` should be for a Rails 2.3.18 app in production to run on Passenger/Unicorn/Puma?

So far I've got:

```
# Require your environment file to bootstrap Rails
require ::File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'

# Dispatch the request
run ActionController::Dispatcher.new
```

but it's loading `development` instead of the correct production environment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It turns out this is a perfect `config.ru`.

The real problem is that Unicorn's `-E` parameter sets `RACK_ENV` and Rails 2.3.18 needs `RAILS_ENV` in order to correctly detect the environment.

So, at the top of `config/environment.rb`, I've set `ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= ENV["RACK_ENV"]` and this is working just great.

Comment: A slightly better config.ru includes static assets: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.11/rails_on_rack.html#rackup